# Magic Transit or Magical Transit, Poxy Everything or Proxy Anything

Tags: difference, american-english, phrase-choice

Cloudflare uses 'Magic Transit' and 'Proxy Anything' and I want to know why.

Comment: This is really a marketing decision,  not a matter of everyday usage.

Answer (score 1):

"Proxy Anything" refers to the fact that whatever a user wants to proxy, they can proxy. Everything is proxiable by the user, but only some things actually are proxied by the user. "Everything" describes the potential things proxied, but "anything" describes what's actually proxied.

Answer (score 0):

The marketing people thought that it sounded better like that.

Perhaps "Magic Transit" sounds like it is "Magic"= really good, wonderful, rather than "magical" = supernatural.

And "anything" can proxy, but not "everything" at once.

But these are not examples of normal grammatical English.